# read javascript object to match if an item exists from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have an javascript array of objects named as obj and another object as finalObj

```
const obj = [{ 'name': 'skip', low: 20, high: 10 },
{ 'name': 'jump', low: 5, high: 20},
{ 'name': 'tall', low: 3, high: 2},
{ 'name': 'wind', low: 5, high: 10},
{ 'name': 'hire', low: 7, high: 6 }]

const finalObj = {
'Shopping mall': {
   'names': ['skip', 'jump'],
   'low': 0,
   'high': 0
},
'Parking garage': {
  'names': ['hire'],
  'low': 0,
  'high': 0
},
'Falling Tower': {
  'names': ['tall', 'wind'],
  'low': 0, 
  'high': 0
}
}
```

Now, if obj array of object with item name matches with finalObj of names, then add low and high values into final Obj.

the final output should be something like this:

```
const finalObj = {
'Shopping mall': {
   'names': ['skip', 'jump'],
   'low': 25,
   'high': 30
},
'Parking garage': {
  'names': ['hire'],
  'low': 7,
  'high': 6
},
'Falling Tower': {
  'names': ['tall', 'wind'],
  'low': 8, 
  'high': 12
}
}
```

I tried to iterate over obj but no luck so far..

```
for (const o in obj) {
 for (const f in Object.entries(finalObj)) {
   if (f[1]['names'].indexOf(obj[o].name >= 0)) {
     console.log("matched name : " + obj[o].name)
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you put all the runnable code into a single snippet, using the `<>` icon? This will encourage people to try.

Comment: Why `f[1]`? `f` is an object, not an array.

Comment: `if (f.names.includes(obj[o].name))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `obj.forEach()` to loop through the array. Then loop through the values in `finalObj` with `Object.values(finalObj).forEach()`.

Then use `includes()` to test whether the `name` from `obj` is in `names`, and add to the `low` and `high` properties.

```js
const obj = [
  { 'name': 'skip', low: 20, high: 10 },
  { 'name': 'jump', low: 5, high: 20},
  { 'name': 'tall', low: 3, high: 2},
  { 'name': 'wind', low: 5, high: 10},
  { 'name': 'hire', low: 7, high: 6 }
]

const finalObj = {
  'Shopping mall': {
     'names': ['skip', 'jump'],
     'low': 0,
     'high': 0
  },
  'Parking garage': {
    'names': ['hire'],
    'low': 0,
    'high': 0
  },
  'Falling Tower': {
    'names': ['tall', 'wind'],
    'low': 0, 
    'high': 0
  }
}

obj.forEach(o =>
  Object.values(finalObj).forEach(f => {
    if (f.names.includes(o.name)) {
      f.low += o.low;
      f.high += o.high;
    }
  }));

console.log(finalObj);
```

Comment: Ouch at the performance hit for repetitive calls to `Object.values`.

Comment: Going for clarity, not performance. If I cared about performance I would create an inverted object that uses the names as keys and increments as values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for ... of` to iterate arrays.

```js
// In this first loop, you want to iterate the
// values of the Object `finalObj`. For that,
// you can use `Object.values(...)`.
for (let fo of Object.values(finalObj)) {
    // Next, a normal `for ... of` works since `obj` is an array.
    for (let o of obj) {
        // Finally, search an array for a value
        // with `Array.includes` like so.
        if (fo.names.includes(o.name)) {
            fo.low += o.low
            fo.high += o.high
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (const o of obj) {
  for (const f in finalObj) {
    if (finalObj[f]['names'].indexOf(o.name) >= 0) {
      finalObj[f]['low'] += o.low;
      finalObj[f]['high'] += o.high;
    }
  }
}
```

[Object.entries(finalObj)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) returns an array of key-value pairs, so when you loop through it using for...in, f will be an array instead of an object. You should use for...of instead to loop over the values directly.

The [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) check is not quite right. You need to check if the index is greater than or equal to 0 (not the value of the property name itself).

Comment: You're not using `Object.entries()`. Was that from an earlier edit?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can do it by this

```
for (const key in finalObj) {
  const names = finalObj[key].names;
  let low = 0;
  let high = 0;
  for (const name of names) {
    const match = obj.find(obj => obj.name === name);
    if (match) {
      low += match.low;
      high += match.high;
    }
  }
  finalObj[key].low = low;
  finalObj[key].high = high;
}
```

The names are taken from an array and I loop through them to find their values and add them to the value at the end I update the finalObj